# Can using too many abbreviations slow down vim?

Tags: abbreviations, performance

Recently I started using the `iabbr` to the best of my abilities. While editing a file I may have sourced as many as 500 abbreviations. I have also noticed that my vim is slowing down recently.
The cursor moves with a lag. Same with switching from insert to normal mode.

Can using too many abbreviations be the reason?

As a general curiosity, up to how many abbreviations can vim handle without crashing?

Comment: I think it is very unlikely abbreviations are the cause of the lag.  It is better to try a blank vim config and start adding things until the slowdown happens.

Comment: I use 2800+ abbreviations for `cpp`, I don't notice any performance issue. You can follow this [post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) to debug your vimrc.